# What types of audio envelopes are there?

Tags: synthesizer, audio, synthesis

I was working with some SNES music and noticed references to ADSR envelopes used for their instruments, however it's not ADSR at all since there is no release when a note ends. (There's no sustain for that matter either since notes may decay despite not having ended.)

From what I've read, SNES instruments have an attack, linear decay, and exponential decay, defined by a duration for attack, duration for decay, amplitude of the end of the linear decay, and a rate of the exponential decay.

Wikipedia references [alternate envelopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(music)#Other_envelopes) such as AHDSR, DADSR, and DAHDSR, but none of these seem to fix how SNES instruments work. I'm almost certain I've seen some kind of ADD or ADD2 envelope definition, but trying to find it seems impossible if it exists at all.

Are there any other common kinds of envelope parameters other than ADSR, AHDSR, DADSR, and DAHDSR, and one that accurately describe the type of envelope used by SNES instruments?

Comment: Note, the "sustain" part is optional in ADSR, and is often set to zero for e.g. pluck type instruments. I'm not sure about two different decays, though.

Comment: Hm, don‘t get your point. As a technical invention you can have as many types of envelopes as you want and describe them by parameters. E.g. think of various kinds of periodic envelopes, including random ones. // You may want to post your question in a synthesizer forum.

Comment: I used to have a soft synth you could draw your own envelope steps in, as many as you like, defining as as you went.

Comment: The SNES SHVC-SOUND chip's S-DSP component [provides](https://snes.nesdev.org/wiki/DSP_envelopes) an ADSR, a `GAIN` control with some pre-programmed ramps, and direct control via the `VOL` register.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, I don't think that wiki is accurate. The "release" on the SNES does not occur on keyoff but rather as soon as the sustain value is reached at the end of the decay time. Once the note is released, the sound stops immediately.